# dynamicArray.push(struct) possible in solidity?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Can push functionality of arrays be used for structure in solidity? Any example will help a lot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract PushStruct {

    struct MyStruct {
        uint field1;
        uint field2;
    }

    MyStruct[] public myStructs;

    function pushStruct() 
        public
        returns(uint arrayLength) 
    {
        MyStruct memory m;
        m.field1 = 1;
        m.field2 = 2;
        myStructs.push(m);
        return myStructs.length;
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: In the document i see the push() operation on a dynamicStorage array returns the size of the array. But when i try to assign the return value to an uint i get below error.

TypeError: Different Number of components on the left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (0).

Can you please help me fix this issue.

Comment: From Solidity V 0.6.0, dynamicStorageArray.push() returns nothing.. So i was getting the abov error.

more info @https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.8/060-breaking-changes.html